# android double drawer: right drawer toggle

Tags: android, double, toggle, drawer

I have read many posts about double drawer, but none of them fixed the right drawer toggle issue.

Android double drawer layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

<!-- content here -->

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"/>


<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In then main activitiy

```
DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
toggle.syncState();
```

There is only one Toggle icon for left drawer. There is not one for the right drawer. ActionBarDrawerToggle does not specify which drawer.

Comment: when you swipe the right one your right drawer does not open ?

Comment: swipe can open the right drawer. Sometimes it is nice to have a toggle icon for it to tell users that there is a right drawer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you can make a work around to show icon for right drawer by your self to put item in your activity menu for opening the right drawer.

put this in your **main_menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_open_right_drawer"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_ab_right_drawer_icon"
        android:title="rightDrawer"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

and put this in your **mainActivity**

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_open_right_drawer)
        drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END);

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I'm sure it is not the best solution for this but it works fine

Comment: Opening a menu item is not intuitive for users who are used to look for a toggle icon in action bar. Can make it to the action bar? Thanks.

Comment: actually this menu is for your action bar it is inflate items in action bar